# Multitape Turing Machine - Check input's primality

Tags: prime-numbers, turing-machines, decidability, decision-problems

I've got this homework for next tomorrow and unfortunatelly I have no idea how to design this machine.

Requirement: Build a 2-tapes Turing Machine, which has a number as input a natural number (unary or binary, doesn't matter) and decide whether it is prime or not.

If anyone can share a design schema or an example to understand how this should be designed it will be perfect.

Thank you!

Comment: Even a one-tape TM for this is easy to make.

Comment: Did you actually get THIS problem ? What would come in my mind is (at least for small numbers) that for each prime $p$ you have to check you use another tape , but still it is not trivial to design checking this divisibility. Maybe, someone has a better idea.

Comment: @markvs OK, if you can show the code of such a turing machine, please write an answer. I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @markvs can you share your idea, please?